# display the "logout" button when the user is logged in and 'connect' when he is not with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logout

**layout.phtml**

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($_SESSION['user'] == false)): ?>
    <p>Hello </p>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="register.php">Sign up</a>
    <a href="userconnect.php">Connect</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to display `logout` button when users logged in and `connect` button when they are not logged in.  But when the form data is sent, it only displays the `connect` button.

**userconnect.phtml**

There is this html form.

```
<div class="user-connect">
  <?php if (isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
    <form action="userconnect.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="email"></label>
                <input type="text" id='email' name='email'>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="password"></label>
                <input type="password" id='password' name='password'>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="enter">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

**userconnect.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST["enter"]) && !empty($_POST["enter"])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) 
    {
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars(md5(md5($_POST['password'])));

        include ("connection.php");
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT ID, email, password, firstName FROM user WHERE email = ?');
        $query->execute([$_POST['email']]);
        $user = $query->fetch();  

        if ($user) {
            if($_POST['password'] == $user['password'] && $_POST['email'] == $user['email'])
            {
                $_SESSION['user'] = [
                    'email' => $user['email'],
                    'id' => $user['ID'] 
                ];
            }
            $message = "Vous etes connectez!";
        } else {
            $message = "Invalide email ou mot de passe!";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Champs obligatoire a saisir";
    }
}

$template = 'userconnect';
include 'layout.phtml';
```

Dumping `$_SESSION['user']`:

```
<?php var_dump(isset($_SESSION['user'])); ?>
```

displays `bool(false)`.

Could you please help me how I can display the `logout` button?

I've searched everywhere and I can't find the solution.

Comment: Did you start the session on the other page where you are doing the comparison?

Comment: Also `htmlspecialchars` should only be used for outputting to a browser. And you should use a more updated hashing algorithm than `md5` (doubling it doesn't make it more secure). You also don't need the `$_POST['email'] == $user['email']` because the SQL already verified that match.

Comment: and you need to change `if($_POST['password'] == $user['password'])` to this: `if( $password == $user['password'])`

Comment: @user3783243  if I start the session on the other page it displays Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST THING**

Replace

```
if($_POST['password'] == $user['password'] && $_POST['email'] == $user['email']
```

with

```
if($password == $user['password'])
```

You don't need `$_POST['email'] == $user['email']` to be checked because you have already checked that in the query with the `WHERE` clause, so you only get the result that matches the email you sent in the `POST` request. So, specifying `$_POST['email'] == $user['email']` is useless once the query returns the matched result (email).

Then, you should use `$password` instead of `$_POST['password']` because you have password field processed into `$password` variable with some hashing.

**SECOND THING**

Don't use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` against user inputs. It only matters when you output things on the page to protect against attacks like `XSS`.

Also, I would like to know how your password is processed in sign up process.

**UPDATE**

As you have mentioned in the comment, you use `password_hash` function to hash the passwords during sign up.

But in the question, you use `md5(md5($_POST['password']))` to hash the input and match against the hashed password in the database. This won't work.

Instead, you should use `password_verify` which is intended to match the input against the hashed password which is generated by `password_hash`.

Here is how you need to use it,

```
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($user) {
    if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = [
            'email' => $user['email'],
            'id' => $user['ID'] 
        ];
        $message = "Vous etes connectez!";
    }
}
```

By the way, you put this statement,

```
$message = "Vous etes connectez!";
```

inside the password verification condition.

That's it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT); $query = $db -> prepare('INSERT INTO user(firstName, lastName, password, email, address, birthday, city, postalCode, country, phoneNumber) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'); 
$query -> execute([ $firstName, $lastName, $password, $email, $address, $birthday, $city, $postalCode, $country, $phoneNumber]);

Comment: Modified the answer. You can now check it out.

Comment: Thank you for yours answers. The mistake was also to not assign the UNIQUE index to email in the database.

Comment: Oh. Yeah. `email` column must be assigned with `UNIQUE` index if the column doesn't need to have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem. If the user is logged in, `$_SESSION['user']` cannot be `false`. Try it like this:

**layout.phtml**

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
    <p>Hello </p>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="register.php">Sign up</a>
    <a href="userconnect.php">Connect</a>
```